# SMARTY - Keyword in string after the 4th word then add remaining words from the truncated string from the 4th word

Tags: php, smarty, smarty2

I have a sting:

```
$string = "this string is a lorem ipsum string"
```

after the 4th word I want to add a keyword like:

```
$keyword = "newword"
```

now the result should look like this

```
$newstring = "this string is a newword lorem ipsum string"
```

how can i handle this with smarty in a tpl-file?

Comment: You could `explode` on spaces then iterate over the return and use modulas operator to check if it is the fourth.

Comment: what have you tried? What errors did you run into?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used Smarty in a long time, but you can do this in PHP and inject into the template or use the PHP in the template:

```
{php}
$array  = explode(' ', $string);
$result = implode(' ', array_merge(array_splice($array, 0, 4), [$keyword], $array));
{/php}
```

- Explode on spaces
- Slice out the first 4 words
- Merge the slice, keyword and original array (minus the slice)
- Implode on a space